# Python: Why does the AND operator work instead of the OR operator in my conditional loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
while englishDecision.casefold() != "points" and englishDecision.casefold() != "percentage":
    print()
    englishDecision = input("ERROR: Specify wether you would like to input the 'points' or 'percentage': ")
```

✅ When I use the AND operator, it prints the error message when it is supposed to and doesn't when it isn't supposed to

❌ When I use the OR operator, it prints the ERROR message when it is supposed to but also when it isn't supposed to

I didn't expect what would happen, I'm just failing to understand why the OR operator doesn't also work

Comment: Because AND expresses the required logic correctly and OR doesn't. With OR the loop executes all the time, because `casefold` will always be unequal to one of those values, as it can't have both of them at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

If you rephrase it to a "real life" example, it may make more sense:

> If the sky is not red, or if the sky is not green

- If the sky is red, "the sky is not green" is true, so the condition is true.
- If the sky is green, "the sky is not red" is true, so the condition is true
- If the sky is blue, both of those are true, so the condition is true.

Because the sky can't be two colors at the same time, that condition can never be false. The same issue applies to your case as well. `englishDecision.casefold()` can not be equal to both "points" and "percentage" at the same time, so the condition can never be false.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `!=` (not equal), which may be the confusing point. `englishDecision.casefold() != "points"` is `True` for everything except "points" and `englishDecision.casefold() != "percentage"` is `True` for everything except "percentage". No matter what you enter, one of those cases will be `True`. And when one case of an `or` is `True`, the entire `or` is `True`.

It may be more clear to write

```
while not (englishDecision.casefold() != "points" or englishDecision.casefold() != "percentage"):
    print()
    englishDecision = input("ERROR: Specify wether you would like
```

But it would be better to write

```
while englishDecision.casefold() not in ("points", "percentage"):
    print()
    englishDecision = input("ERROR: Specify wether you would like
```

And if your comparison list is large, it would be worth putting it into a `set` first

```
proper_decisions = set(("points", "percentage"))
while englishDecision.casefold() not in proper_decisions:
    print()
    englishDecision = input("ERROR: Specify wether you would like
```

Answer (score 0):

in the case with `and`:

(just write here an The truth table)

```
0 0 0
0 1 0
1 0 0
1 1 1
```

end - prints the error message (only if both statements are true, only in one case, perfect)

and in the case with `or`:

(just write here an The truth table again)

```
0 0 0
0 1 1
1 0 1
1 1 1
```

and we see that the error message does not appear only if both statements are true. the only problem is that they are not equal only in 1 case, when the string is equal to both statements at once, which cannot be real.

If you were to use the or operator, the loop would continue if either condition is true. This means if english decision is "points", it is not "percentage", so the second condition is true and the loop continue, which is not what you want. The or operator is not appropriate here because you want the loop to exit when english decisions matches either "points" or "percentage", not to continue.